# nodejs res.render local variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

i've been doing some work on how to display the correct things depend on the user's choice.

To be more specific, imagine **a course page which allow you to see which quiz belong to which course**.

On the course page, **the quiz display will be hyperlinks with href such as:** href='http:localhost:3000/quizs?getQuiz=*theQuizName*'

**When select the link, it go to another page which display the selected quiz a quiz page**. And *theQuizName* **is the name of the selected quiz**.

**All the  links will go the the same page**, the only thing that changes is *theQuizName* **to change the quiz displayed on the quiz page**

in the server side, i intend to send theQuizName from the url (**http://localhost:3000/quizs?getQuiz=MyFirstQuiz**) to the client side like so:

```
app.get('/quizs', function(req, res){
    var toClient = req.params('getQuiz');
    res.render('quizess.ejs', {quizToDisplay: toClient});
});
```

But the problem is that i don't know where the local variable *(quizToDisplay: toClient)* is sent to nor how to get it.

So that i can based on the sent data *(quizToDisplay: toClient)* to change the quiz to display on the quiz page *(quizess.ejs)* with the client side javascript

Comment: app.get("/quiz/:id",...) would give much nicer urls...

Comment: i know about that kind of params but the main problem i'm having is to pass the info from the param to the client side to i can use it

Answer (score 0):

Use `<%= quizToDisplay %>` on ejs anywhere to print the variable.

Comment: could you please be more specific, like where do i put the <%= quizToDisplay %> in the code

Comment: In whichever ejs file you're rendering. In this case `quizess.ejs`. Put the code anywhere in the file and it will print.

Comment: so i just put that code into my quizess.ejs file and i can get the quizToDisplay from there

Comment: ok the <%> thing diffinately work but it seems to be something undefined and i can't seem to use it as a variable or data. can you explain more about this code or post the link you got it from ?